# I want to check the value in a field is the current date

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a field that has a date and i want to check the value in it is the current date in the format YYYY-MM-DD.  How can i do this.  Thanks in advance for any help given

I tried this

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
         const newDate = new Date(win.Date());
cy.get('#datefrom').should('be.visible').and('have.value', newDate)
```

but am getting this error

Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<input#datefrom.form-control>' to have value Wed, 05 Apr 2023 15:50:37 GMT, but the value was '2023-04-05'

Question - How can i change the format of newDate show it just shows the value as YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Convert to an ISO string and take just the first part

```
const currentDateYyyyMmDd = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)
console.log(currentDateYyyyMmDd)
```

Whose output is currently this:

```
2023-04-05
```

In your case, try this:

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
         const newDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10));
cy.get('#datefrom').should('be.visible').and('have.value', newDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tests should be conducted at a fixed date to avoid variations due to current date.

The example to follow is here [Specify a now timestamp](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock#Now)

```js
const now = new Date(2021, 3, 14) // month is 0-indexed

cy.clock(now)
cy.visit('/index.html')
cy.get('#datefrom').should('have.value', '2021-04-14')
```